# How to show all value that have a null entry in a specific column

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am wanting to bring forward a CSV file containing all users `Name`, `SamAccountName` and `Description`, however we have noticed that there are several people who do not have descriptions. What I am looking for is how to edit my existing code (I know there's a simple way to do it I just can't remember it) so that is filters my output so it only shows users who have no description.

```psh
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties Name,SamAccountName,Description -SearchBase "DC=REMOVED,DC=com" |
? { $_.Enabled -notlike "FALSE" } | 
Select Name,SamAccountName,Description |
Export-Csv "C:\scripts\NoDescriptionUsers.csv"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add another condition in your `Where-Object` scriptblock since you can't filter empty values with an LDAP-Query AFAIK. One suggestion:

```psh
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties Name,SamAccountName,Description -SearchBase "DC=REMOVED,DC=com" |
? { $_.Enabled -notlike "FALSE" -and [string]::IsNullOrEmpty($_.Description.Trim()) } |
Select Name,SamAccountName,Description |
Export-Csv "C:\scripts\NoDescriptionUsers.csv"
```

Personally I would also move the enabled-check into a filter in `Get-ADUser` to speed things up. Now the DC will only send you enabled users instead of all users. Try:

```psh
Get-ADUser -Filter { Enabled -eq $true } -Properties Name,SamAccountName,Description -SearchBase "DC=REMOVED,DC=com" |
? { [string]::IsNullOrEmpty($_.Description.Trim()) } |
Select Name,SamAccountName,Description |
Export-Csv "C:\scripts\NoDescriptionUsers.csv"
```

Comment: Besides the intent being clearer does `[string]::IsNullOrEmpty($_.Description)` have advantages over `!($_.Description)` as that is what I would have answered.

Comment: I confirmed this to be working, but right before you answered it I found another solution which was adding the condition $_.Description like $null that also works, I will probably using yours as it looks more official (joke, but seriously). I also took your advice and moved the enabled-check into the filter. Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: LDAP can most certainly filter on empty values: `"(!(description=*))"`

Comment: @Matt Easier to read and more fool-proof, but both should work. I usually use `? { $_.Description }` myself, but I have had some strange cases with it. @MathiasR.Jessen wouldn't `=*` also match "nothing"? Anyways, let me rephrase it to, there isn't a way to filter blanks using `-Filter` AFAIK. :)